# Python: stream a large file upload not working

Tags: python, post, optimization, python-requests, stream

I tried to upload files as below:

```
data = {'type': 'gallary', 'username': 'a457'}
url = "url/to/upload"

with open('filepath', "rb") as file:
    files = {
        "file": (
            'gallary.zip',
            file,
        )
    }
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

The file size is quite big for some users, however I have a limited RAM(memory). When the post request is made, the program gets killed with error `out of memory`. My understanding was that using `with open('filepath', "rb") as file` gives a file like object and stream the file upload.

Then I tried something like below as suggested by many answers here:

```
encoder = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        "file": (
            'gallary.zip',
             file,
        ),
        **data,
    },
)
response = requests.post(url, data=encoder)
```

In this case, I get error `415 Client Error: Unsupported Media Type`. What is the actual way to stream a large file in python where I need to pass data along with the file?

Comment: If you assume help, share a minimal working example please. What is fileparh? Is it a single file or a path? Not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you like to do is, upload multiple files, like:

```
import requests

data = {'type': 'gallary', 'username': 'a457'}
url = "url/to/upload"

test_files = {
    "file_1": open("my_file1.txt", "rb"),
    "file_2": open("my_file_2.txt", "rb"),
    "file_3": open("my_file_3.txt", "rb")
}

response = requests.post(url, data=data, files = test_files)
```

Alternative, if you would like upload only a single huge file you can also use `with open()` , like in the doc [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)

Comment: This is same as mine and also crashes the server because it reads the whole file

Answer (score 0):

When working with large files, it’s important to stream the file rather than load it into memory all at once. One way to do this is to use the requests library’s stream parameter when making the request. Refer below:

```
import requests

data = {'type': 'gallary', 'username': 'a457'}
url = "url/to/upload"

with open('filepath', "rb") as file:
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, files={'file': file}, stream=True)
```

In the above code, the **stream=True** parameter tells requests to stream the file rather than loading it into memory all at once.

Comment: This loads the whole file in memory and crashes the server. Somehow the post request reads the whole file instead of streaming it.